# Python import serial, no module named serial error

Tags: python, pyserial

pyserial and serial should be installed, but there is an error `no module named serial`

```
jess@DESKTOP-4DGO4EU /cygdrive/c/fyptrial/fypcnn
$ python -m "import serial"
C:\Users\jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: No module named import serial

jess@DESKTOP-4DGO4EU /cygdrive/c/fyptrial/fypcnn
$ python -m pip install serial
Requirement already satisfied: serial in c:\users\jess\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (0.0.97)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.17.1 in c:\users\jess\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from serial) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601>=0.1.12 in c:\users\jess\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from serial) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=3.13 in c:\users\jess\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from serial) (5.1)

jess@DESKTOP-4DGO4EU /cygdrive/c/fyptrial/fypcnn
$ python -m pip install pyserial
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\jess\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (3.4)
```

Comment: Have you already tried the `-c` option? :-) (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

`-m` means module-name, see https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

To run a command you have to use `-c`, so in your case:

`python -c "import serial"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't use the pip version for your version of python. 
run `python -V`
and if it shows `Python 3` 
try `pip3 install serial`